# Allocate random zone to data frame

Tags: r, random, sampling

I'd like to allocate a random zone to all the elements in a data frame.

Say data frame has the structure:

```
df:
age-height-nation -  zone
13,'tall','American', -
.....
11,'tall','S.american', -
```

and I want to fill the column [zone], being the possible values for zone ('A','B','C'). The probabilities of each zone vary. For ex:

```
prob(A)=0.1
prob(B)=0.3
prob(C)=0.6
```

How could I allocate a zone to all elements in df, being probabilities as said?

Thanks in advance,              p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df$zone <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], nrow(df), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.6))
```

You can replcae `LETTERS[1:3]` with `c("A", "B", "C")` or whatever strings you want.